# How to create a logic that detects special characters in switch case (Error Handling)

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I would like to add a logic that detects numbers and other special characters in the user's input (aside from a space, if they are not strictly alphabet characters) to output an error to try again. I'd love to read your advice.

use any or all of AINXBJQY to test input.

```js
function myFunction() {
  
var myArray = ["60","50", "20", "30", "15", "10"];
   
    var workout = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  
  
var text = "";
for(const char of workout.toUpperCase()){
  var randomJumpingJacks = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  var randomCrunches = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
  
    switch(char) {
        case "A":
        case "I":
        case "N":
        case "X":
            text += randomJumpingJacks;
            text += " Jumping Jacks";
                  
        break;
        case "B":
        case "J":
        case "Q":
        case "Y":
            text += randomCrunches;
            text += " Crunches";       
          break;
          case " ":
            /*text += " break ";*/
        break;
       
        default:
        text += "Place holder for Error Text ...";    
    }
  text +=" "
  text +="<br>"
}
  
    document.getElementById("excercise").innerHTML = text;
  
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Input some characters  and click the button.</p>
<p>Your excericse routine will display based on your input.</p>

<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p>
  <span id="reps"></span>
  <span id="excercise"></span>
  </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What sort of error? A `I have never heard of that ...` for every single character (which is what your code already accomplishes), or an error before any characters start being iterated over, or what?

Comment: Also, you might consider fixing your snippet - `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about the syntaxerror, the text  was just a random place holder for the error (Try again), i kept receiving multiple I have never heard of that.. each time a non alphabet character was added

Comment: basically what i'm trying to achieve is if the user inputs any (so not more than 0)  non alphabet characters, to scan the it and give the error. And I want the error to be displayed one time, not multiple times even though the user might have input multiple non alphabet characters

Comment: Why do you have case "A", case "I", case "N", case "B", case "J", case "Q"? What do you want program to do when it finds "A", "I", "N", "B", "J" or "Q"? It would be even better if you could give us exapmles of inputs and outputs for your program. Something like: if you enter "abcd" as input for program to output "abcd", or when you enter "a12b" for program to output "error".

Comment: hi there, this just a simplified example code, if i threw all the letters in there it would be too long of a code, and I'm trying to get a grasp of the concept without the extra fluff (which is why i mentioned to use AINXBJQY to test), bu i'd like if when the user inputs a12b, a12b?, etc..  to output the error because they contain non alphabet characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a regular expression: check if `[^a-z ]` matches the input (that is, if there are any characters other than alphabetical ones and spaces). If there is a match, show the error and return immediately (don't proceed to the loop or the `switch` statement):

```
if (/[^a-z ]/i.test(workout)) {
  exercise.textContent = 'Please enter letters and spaces only';
  return;
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  const myArray = ["60", "50", "20", "30", "15", "10"];
  const workout = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  const exercise = document.getElementById("excercise");
  if (/[^a-z ]/i.test(workout)) {
    exercise.textContent = 'Please enter letters and spaces only';
    return;
  }
  
  
  let text = "";
  for (const char of workout.toUpperCase()) {
    const randomJumpingJacks = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];
    const randomCrunches = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

    switch (char) {
      case "A":
      case "I":
      case "N":
      case "X":
        text += randomJumpingJacks;
        text += " Jumping Jacks";

        break;
      case "B":
      case "J":
      case "Q":
      case "Y":
        text += randomCrunches;
        text += " Crunches";
        break;
      case " ":
        /*text += " break ";*/
        break;

      default:
        text += "Place holder for Error Text ...";
    }
    text += " "
    text += "<br>"
  }

  document.getElementById("excercise").innerHTML = text;


}
```

```html
<p>Input some characters and click the button.</p>
<p>Your excericse routine will display based on your input.</p>

<input id="myInput" type="text">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p>
  <span id="reps"></span>
  <span id="excercise"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for the thorough explanation!